# Posting to a Google Forms form using NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, forms, post, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am trying to post a string to a Google Form using NSURLRequest. The method seems to be getting called, but the post to the Google Form doesn't appear. This is the code I am using:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1T9M6B_k4tiQcSPP5iS2jyU7DCkoRC1jFVql_eQDy9ek/formResponse"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = @"entry.757751040=Test sent from iOS App";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

if (connection){
    NSLog(@"Connecting...");
}
```

I created [this](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1T9M6B_k4tiQcSPP5iS2jyU7DCkoRC1jFVql_eQDy9ek/viewform) form solely for testing purposes. "Connecting..." gets logged, so I know the connection is being made, but the string does not appear in the Google Forms Spreadsheet. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code only checks if `connection` is not `nil`

```
if (connection){
    NSLog(@"Connecting...");
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (connection != nil){
    NSLog(@"Connecting...");
}
```

As such, it has nothing to do with an actual connection to the URL.

The method `initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate` which you are using will perform the request immediately. This means that you have to perform the operations in another order if you want your params to work:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1T9M6B_k4tiQcSPP5iS2jyU7DCkoRC1jFVql_eQDy9ek/formResponse"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = @"entry.757751040=Test sent from iOS App";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Along with this, consider implementing [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html).